# Error when calling FORGE API via forge-apis library

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We work with Autodesk FORGE REST API with [forge-apis](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client) library. Since today we have an unstable behaviour when calling its methods. Here is the error:

> address: “34.203.81.163” code: “ETIMEDOUT” errno: “ETIMEDOUT” port:
>   443 syscall: “connect” message: “connect ETIMEDOUT 34.203.81.163:443”
>   stack: “Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.203.81.163:443↵    at
>   TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1162:14)”

Is there something we need to change in our code or we're getting to some threshold in a number of API calls or this is a temporary internal instability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default HTTP timeout, 60000 milliseconds, in the [src/ApiClient.js](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/5bf1470155d4bc98985db38bcbdd73fe547d14bd/src/ApiClient.js). When you received this message, it means that you didn't get the response from Forge server after 60000 milliseconds. Please try to increase the timeout value of the `ApiClient`. Here are two ways to make this change:

Method 1:

```
var bucketsApi = new ForgeSDK.BucketsApi();
bucketsApi.apiClient.timeout = 2 * 60000;

var objectsApi = new ForgeSDK.ObjectsApi();
objectsApi.apiClient.timeout = 2 * 60000;
```

Method 2:

```
var apiClient = new ForgeSDK.ApiClient();
apiClient.timeout = 2 * 60000;

var bucketsApi = new ForgeSDK.BucketsApi( apiClient );
var objectsApi = new ForgeSDK.ObjectsApi( apiClient );
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers,